# Failed to Start MYSQL community server 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
root@ubuntu:~# /etc/init.d/mysql start
[....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
root@ubuntu:~# journalctl -xe
Jul 06 20:05:32 ubuntu dhclient[20225]: DHCPDISCOVER on ens192 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0xeae9763f)
Jul 06 20:05:47 ubuntu dhclient[20225]: DHCPDISCOVER on ens192 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0xeae9763f)
Jul 06 20:05:48 ubuntu NetworkManager[1200]: <warn>  [1562423748.9895] dhcp4 (ens192): request timed out
Jul 06 20:05:48 ubuntu NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1562423748.9896] dhcp4 (ens192): state changed unknown -> timeout
Jul 06 20:05:49 ubuntu NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1562423749.0223] dhcp4 (ens192): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 20225
Jul 06 20:05:49 ubuntu NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1562423749.0224] dhcp4 (ens192): state changed timeout -> done
Jul 06 20:05:49 ubuntu NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1562423749.0231] device (ens192): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Jul 06 20:05:49 ubuntu NetworkManager[1200]: <warn>  [1562423749.0237] device (ens192): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
Jul 06 20:05:49 ubuntu NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1562423749.0262] device (ens192): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jul 06 20:05:49 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1102]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::674:2a59:2a68:e35b on ens192.
Jul 06 20:05:49 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1102]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface ens192.IPv6 with address fe80::674:2a59:2a68:e35b.
Jul 06 20:05:49 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1102]: Interface ens192.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jul 06 20:05:49 ubuntu NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1562423749.0358] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1'
Jul 06 20:05:49 ubuntu NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1562423749.0535] device (ens192): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (0423d3d0-cbfb-3dd8-905d-273cd5428ac5)
Jul 06 20:05:49 ubuntu NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1562423749.0547] device (ens192): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jul 06 20:05:49 ubuntu NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1562423749.0563] device (ens192): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul 06 20:05:49 ubuntu NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1562423749.0580] device (ens192): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jul 06 20:05:49 ubuntu NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1562423749.0619] dhcp4 (ens192): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jul 06 20:05:49 ubuntu NetworkManager[1200]: <info>  [1562423749.0970] dhcp4 (ens192): dhclient started with pid 20267
Jul 06 20:05:49 ubuntu dhclient[20267]: DHCPDISCOVER on ens192 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x1b1fef15)
Jul 06 20:05:50 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1102]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface ens192.IPv6 with address fe80::674:2a59:2a68:e35b.
Jul 06 20:05:50 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1102]: New relevant interface ens192.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jul 06 20:05:50 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1102]: Registering new address record for fe80::674:2a59:2a68:e35b on ens192.*.
Jul 06 20:05:52 ubuntu dhclient[20267]: DHCPDISCOVER on ens192 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x1b1fef15)
Jul 06 20:05:52 ubuntu mysqld[20194]: Initialization of mysqld failed: 0
Jul 06 20:05:52 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 06 20:05:52 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jul 06 20:05:52 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 06 20:05:52 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 06 20:05:53 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 06 20:05:53 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Jul 06 20:05:53 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Jul 06 20:05:53 ubuntu audit[20377]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=20377 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 06 20:05:53 ubuntu kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1562423753.324:274): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=20377 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul 06 20:05:53 ubuntu audit[20381]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/etc/my.cnf" pid=20381 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=123 ouid=0
Jul 06 20:05:53 ubuntu kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1562423753.364:275): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/etc/my.cnf" pid=20381 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="
Jul 06 20:05:58 ubuntu dhclient[20267]: DHCPDISCOVER on ens192 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x1b1fef15)
Jul 06 20:06:06 ubuntu dhclient[20267]: DHCPDISCOVER on ens192 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x1b1fef15)
Jul 06 20:06:14 ubuntu dhclient[20267]: DHCPDISCOVER on ens192 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10 (xid=0x1b1fef15)
lines 1451-1506/1506 (END)
```

Comment: Check in the `/var/log/mysql/error.log` file if there is additional info.